# google search engine architecture- how do so many concurrent users do a search on it

Tags: scalability

With millions of users searching for so many things on google, yahoo and so on.
How can the server handle so many concurrent searches?
I have no clue as to how they made it so scalable.
Any insight into their architecture would be welcomed.

Comment: Considering how thousands of great Google engineers have been working on this for over a decade, it's probably fair to say a single ServerFault question won't do it any justice

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous case studies and talks by Google engineers available online with a little searching.  Suffice it to say that Google Search is **highly distributed** and pushed out datacenters all over the world.

There's a ton of information available over at http://highscalability.com/google-architecture.

Comment: One example is the paper published years ago on disk failures (at the time, estimates were they had 800,000 servers).  And the paper on MapReduce, just to name a two.

Answer (score 2):

As has been mentioned, the networks and architecture of large-scale websites is highly distributed across many data centers and tens of thousands of servers.  If you're interested in how this works, I'd recommend a book called [Scalable Internet Architectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/067232699X) which describes some of the concepts and theories behind scalable and distributed systems.

Comment: One estimate I read a few years ago said 800,000 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, they use 100,000's of servers, and MapReduce.  Massively parallel.